# Can we use active-merchant authorized.net CIM API's to retrieve transaction details from the gateway?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, authorize.net-cim

Active-Merchant doesn't have any API for retrieving details of any existing transaction from authorized.net.I have seen authorized.net provides an API `getTransactionDetailsRequest` for that but active-merchant doesn't .

Answer (score 1):

> you can  use this forked version for that

```
https://github.com/jaswinder97/active_merchant
```